# Array extension, Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension to Array in Xcode's playground. I want to write a function that will modify the array so that it will be filled with 0s when the function is called. The code I'm attempting to use is this:

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    mutating func zero() {
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            self[i] = 0 // ERROR - Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not run, because of the error at:

```
self[i] = 0
```

However, if I try to 'get' a value from self, I have no issues. For example:

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    mutating func zero() {
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            print(self[i])
        }
    }
}
```

has no errors and runs as expected.

**So my question is; Why can't I modify the array?**

Also, Replacing:

```
self[i] = 0
```

with,

```
self.append(0)
```

also results in an error. (Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)')

So it won't let me modify self at all it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you do the following:

```
extension Array where Element: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    mutating func zero() {
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            self[i] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

You must constrain the type of the elements allowed, because you can't, for example, zero out an array of `String`s.

It's important to remember, when extending something like an `Array`, that you take into account what types of elements are valid for the method you're adding. If it requires elements of a certain type, you constrain on it and then it will work. That way you can only use your `zero()` method on `Array`s containing ints. You might define a different version for an array of `String`s that replaces everything in the array with the string "zero", for example, and that implementation will only be used on the type that you constrain it to as well.

Comment: Or `where Element: IntegerLiteralConvertible` to make it slightly more universal (for arrays of integers or floating point values).

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, made that change!

Comment: Thanks Gavin and @Martin R! This fixes the error. I'll have to delve into this topic a little deeper, later on today.